# Heterogeneity Measures - Meta-analysis in Python

Tags: python, statistics

I want to make a function which will compute the heterogeneity measures for meta-analyses. I found the following function on GitHub,but I think that this function doesn't fit on my purpose and it must be altered in order to be correct.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# y1 - a numeric vector indicating the observed effect sizes in the collected studies; they are assumed to be normally distributed.
# s2 - a numeric vector indicating the within-study variances.
# n_resam - a positive integer indicating the number of resampling iterations for calculating p-values of test statistics and 95% confidence interval of heterogeneity measures.

def altmeta(y1, s2, n_resam = 1000):
       def metahet_base(y1, s2):
              if(len(y1) != len(s2) | all(i<0 for i in s2)):
                     print('error in the input data.')
                     
              n = len(y1)
              w = [(1/x) for x in s2]
              mu_bar = sum(a*b for a,b in zip(w,y1))/sum(w)
  
              out = []
  
              Q = sum(a*b for a,b in zip(w,[(x - mu_bar)**2 for x in y1]))
              H = np.sqrt(Q/(n - 1))
              I2 = (Q-(len(s2)-1))/Q
              tau2_DL = (Q - n + 1)/(sum(w) - sum([x**2 for x in w])/sum(w))
              tau2_DL = max(0, tau2_DL)
              out.extend([mu_bar,Q,H,I2,tau2_DL])

              out1 = pd.DataFrame(out)
              out1['index']=['Weighted_Mean', 'Q', 'H', 'I2', 'tau2_DL']
              out1 = out1.set_index('index', drop=True)
  
              return(Q,I2,out1)

       q,i2,out0 = metahet_base(y1,s2)

       def out_temp_fn(y_t):
              y_temp = []
              for i in range(7):
                     y_temp.append(y_t[0][i])  
              out_temp = metahet_base(y_temp,s2)
              return(out_temp)
       
       out_resam_param = [] 
       q_resam_param = []

       for i in range(n_resam):
              y_t1 = np.random.normal(out0[0][0],[np.sqrt(s2)])
              out_resam_param.append(out_temp_fn(y_t1)[2])

       for i in range(n_resam):
              q_resam_param.append(out_resam_param[i].loc['Q',:][0])
       
       p_Q = (sum([b > q for b in q_resam_param]) + 1)/(n_resam + 1)
       
       return(q,i2,p_Q)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use PythonMeta, https://pypi.org/project/PythonMeta/

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me a lot !

Comment: You`re welcome .Are you going to run a meta-analysis in Python?

Comment: Yes. It's a university  task for the lesson of  'Advanced topics of Biostatistics'